# Entropy of reaction from these givens?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

Reaction that happens at 380 Kelvin

$\begin{align} \Delta S^\circ _{sys} &=\pu{-130 J/molK}\\
C_p(\ce{C2H4})&=\pu{43.6 J/molK}\\
C_p(\ce{C2H5OH})&=\pu{65.9 J/molK}\\
C_p(\ce{H2O})&=\pu{33.6  J/molK}  \end{align}$

I need to calculate the $\Delta S $ for reaction:

$$\ce{C2H4(g) + H2O(g) <=> C2H5OH(g)}$$

I really have no try, i can calculate it if i was given the entropies for each reactant/product and do products-reactant. but can someone give me the formula needed to solve this?
I'm given the system standard entropy and heat capacities only.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: "380k Ds(sys)=-130. Cp(c2h4)=43.6. Cp(c2h5OH)65.9. Cp(h20) 33.6." makes no sense. Please format chemical formulae, physical quantities as well as their units and symbols appropriately. Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: The reaction happens at 380K (temperature) and then the Cps were given in J/K*mol of the reactants and products, and im also given the system standart entropy which is -130. 
that's all really. @andselisk

Comment: What is the meaning of Ds(sys) = -130 ? Unit ? What is the relationship or the difference between dS and Ds ? Why do you have to calculate something where you already have got the answer ?

Comment: Thats what i dont understand, they are given me the standart entropy for the system and i need the standard entropy for the specific reaction, i added a picture in the OP to make it clear of whats given @Maurice

Answer (score 1):

For an isobaric process you can integrate the expression $dS = dq/T = C_p dT/T$ to compute the entropy change at another temperature. Since the heat capacities are assumed constant you can proceed as follows:

$$\begin{align}\Delta S_{\pu{380 K}}^\circ &= \Delta S_{\pu{298.15 K}}^\circ + \sum_i \nu_i\int_{298.15 K}^\pu{380 K} \frac{C_{p,i}}{T}dT\\&= \Delta S_{\pu{298.15 K}}^\circ + \int_{298.15 K}^\pu{380 K}\frac{dT}{T} \sum_i \nu_i C_{p,i} \\ &=  \pu{-130 J/molK} + \ln\left( \frac{380}{298.15}\right) \left( 65.9 - 43.6-33.6   \right)\pu{ J/molK}\\ &=  \pu{-133 J/molK}  \end{align}$$ where the stoichiometric coefficients $\nu_i$ are $\pm 1$.